# Is it possible to bind two ports to a website using Wix and IIS7?

Tags: iis, wix, wix3.5

The Wix code is as follows:

```
  <iis:WebSite Id="TheWebSite" Description="My web Site" Directory="IISWEBROOT">
    <iis:WebAddress Id="MyWebSiteAllUnassigned" Port="80" /> 
    <iis:WebAddress Id="MyWebSiteAllUnassignedSSL" Port="443" Secure="yes" />
```

However during install the Windows Process Activation Service crashes and the first port is not set. It's not clear exactly what point during the install the service crashes. Is it possible to set two ports like this?

(The Default Web Site has had it's ports changed to something other than 80 and 443.)

Comment: We've created a test applictaion and it is possible, there's obviously some interaction between our existing IIS custom actions and the double port configuration that's causing our problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. One of our other custom actions was incorrectly clearing the bindings before the end of installation.